# Get claims for service using Windows validation/authentication

Tags: wcf, security, wshttpbinding

I have the following code which was validation using username & password.
How can I use Windows credentials instead?

```
private static SecurityToken GetClaims(string serviceurl, string username, string password)
    {
        bool isincurrentusercontext = String.IsNullOrEmpty(username); 
        WS2007HttpBinding binding = new WS2007HttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
        binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;

        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(GetStsUrl(isincurrentusercontext)));
        WSTrustChannelFactory trustChannelFactory;

        if (!isincurrentusercontext)
        {
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
            trustChannelFactory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(binding, endpoint);
            trustChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = username;
            trustChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;
        }
        else
            trustChannelFactory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(new KerberosWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential), endpoint);

        trustChannelFactory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
        trustChannelFactory.Credentials.UseIdentityConfiguration = true;

        WSTrustChannel channel = null;

        RequestSecurityToken rst = new RequestSecurityToken(RequestTypes.Issue);
        rst.AppliesTo = new EndpointReference(serviceurl);
        rst.KeyType = KeyTypes.Bearer;

        channel = (WSTrustChannel)trustChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
        SecurityToken token = channel.Issue(rst);
        ((IChannel)channel).Close();
        channel = null;

        trustChannelFactory.Close();
        trustChannelFactory = null;

        return token;

    }
```

If I change,

```
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
```

to

```
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;
```

and remove these two statements,

```
trustChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = username;
trustChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;
```

and when i run this statement,

```
SecurityToken token = channel.Issue(rst);
```

I get the following error,

> Secure channel cannot be opened because security negotiation with the
>   remote endpoint has failed. This may be due to absent or incorrectly
>   specified EndpointIdentity in the EndpointAddress used to create the
>   channel. Please verify the EndpointIdentity specified or implied by
>   the EndpointAddress correctly identifies the remote endpoint

Comment: Did you ever find your solution?